# Native sql with join on custom select reforming to Java Criteria API & JPA Specifications

Tags: jpa, criteria-api

I have an entity with the following signature, and I need all the records where notUniqueID is the latest of its kind. For the sake of simplicity lets assume that endDate is never null.

```
@Entity 
@Table
public class MyClass {
    @Id
    private Long uniqueID;
    private Long notUniqueID;
    private LocalDate endDate;
}
```

So for example

```
1 | "abcd" | "1 january", 
2 | "efgh" | "1 january", 
3 | "efgh" | "1 june", 
4 | "ijkl" | "1 january"
```

should result in:

```
1 | "abcd" | "1 january",  
3 | "efgh" | "1 june", 
4 | "ijkl" | "1 january"
```

Currently this is being done in a native sql way like this:

```
select * from MyClass a
inner join (select notUniqueID, max(endDate) as maxDate from MyClass group by notUniqueID) b on a.notUniqueID = b.notUniqueID and a.endDate = b.maxDate
```

basicly just a group by to fetch the latest date, and join on itself to only include records with these cmbinations. How can I translate this to a JPA specification?

```
public static Specification<MyClass> aNiceNameForThisFn() {
    return (myClass, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        //wut comes here?
        return null;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a working solution without the inner join, using a subquery to compare with in the where clause.

```
public static Specification<MyClass> latestStuff() {
    return (record, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Subquery<LocalDate> innerQuery = criteriaQuery.subquery(LocalDate.class);
        Root<MyClass> inner = innerQuery.from(MyClass.class);

        innerQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.greatest(innerCompany.get("endDate")))
            .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(record.get("notUniqueID"), inner.get("notUniqueID")))
            .groupBy(inner.get("notUniqueID"));

        return criteriaBuilder.equal(record.get("endDate"), innerQuery);
} ;
```

}